# Python - Using an array index that depends on an input value

Tags: python, arrays, indices

I am trying to write a mathematical program in a program called pyomo (a python library). Below, model is an object I declared already, `BRANCH` is a set; `model.branch_scpt`, `model.M`, `model.branch_tbus`, and `model.branch_fbus` are all parameter lists that are loaded as input when the code executes (They all have dimension = BRANCH). Additionally, `model.bus_angle`, `model.line_flow`, and `model.z_line` are lists of decision variables (all also of dimension BRANCH). This is the definition of one of my constraint types, where `j` is in `BRANCH`:

```
def Line_FlowA_rule(model,j):    

    return ( model.branch_scpt[j]*( model.bus_angle[model.branch_tbus[j]]
                                    - model.bus_angle[model.branch_fbus[j]] )
            - model.line_flow[j] + (1 - model.z_line[j]) * model.M[j] >= 0 )

model.Line_FlowA = Constraint(model.BRANCH, rule=LineFlowA_rule)
```

Notice that the element `model.bus_angle[j]` referenced in constraint `Line_FlowA[j]` depends on the element that `model.branch_tbus[j]` returns (similarly, the element that `model.branch_fbus[j]` returns). However, `model.branch_tbus[j]` is a data input value and I believe this is what is causing the following error:

```
"Unexpected exception while running model arpatest_nbp_constraint.py
        Unable to index variable bus_angle using supplied index with unhashable type: '_ParamValue'"
```

In order to make the function neater, I tried to redefine the function as follows:

```
def Line_FlowA_rule(model,j):

    t = model.branch_tbus[j]
    f = model.branch_fbus[j]

    return ( model.branch_scpt[j]*( model.bus_angle[f]
                                    - model.bus_angle[t] )
            - model.line_flow[j] + (1 - model.z_line[j]) * model.M[j] >= 0 )

model.Line_FlowA = Constraint(model.BRANCH, rule=Line_FlowA_rule)
```

but I obtained the same error.

Lastly, to convert the values t and f into immutable types I tried:

```
def Line_FlowA_rule(model,j):

    t = tuple(model.branch_tbus[j])
    f = tuple(model.branch_fbus[j])

    return ( model.branch_scpt[j]*( model.bus_angle[f]
                                    - model.bus_angle[t] )
            - model.line_flow[j] + (1 - model.z_line[j]) * model.M[j] >= 0 )

model.Line_FlowA = Constraint(model.BRANCH, rule=Line_FlowA_rule)
```

This led to the error:

```
ERROR: Unexpected exception while running model arpatest_nbp_constraint.py
        '_ParamValue' object is not iterable
```

Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong here? I am new to python so it is probably something basic. Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you tell us what line the error points to?  It seems likely that either `model.branch_tbus` or `model.branch_tbus[j]` (or the equivalent on "`fbus`") is not an iterable type (list, tuple, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Furst time seeing this, but inptecting the source, we can see, that `class _ParamValue` defined [here](https://software.sandia.gov/trac/coopr/browser/coopr.pyomo/trunk/coopr/pyomo/base/param_repn.py) is extending `class NumericConstant`, defined [here](https://software.sandia.gov/trac/coopr/browser/coopr.pyomo/trunk/coopr/pyomo/base/numvalue.py), from code we can learn there is attribute `value`, so the only thing i can suggest is to change code something like that:

```
def Line_FlowA_rule(model,j):

    t = model.branch_tbus[j].value
    f = model.branch_fbus[j].value

    return ( model.branch_scpt[j]*( model.bus_angle[f]
                                    - model.bus_angle[t] )
            - model.line_flow[j] + (1 - model.z_line[j]) * model.M[j] >= 0 )

model.Line_FlowA = Constraint(model.BRANCH, rule=Line_FlowA_rule)
```

But that can work of course if those parameters are holding indexes for other parameters.

Comment: Thank you very much! This fixed everything. I wish I could vote but I don't have a high enough reputation. You are great!

Comment: @user1246364 Clearly you can accept answer if it's satisfied your needs